# Error message showing "Login Failed for user " when connecting the database installed in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698900/cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for)

I customized a windows application using C#.net (vs 2008) and SQL Server 2005, which works well on windows XP OS. When I tried to work the same application on Windows7, I am getting an error message..

> Cannot Open database 'db' requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'user-pc'.

I didnt modify any code in the application.

I changed the App.config file as shown below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="constr" value="packet size=4096;integrated security=SSPI;data source=user-pc;persist security info=False;initial catalog=db"></add>
    <!--   User application and configured property settings go here.-->
    <!--   Example: <add key="settingName" value="settingValue"/> -->
    <add key="DataGrid1.ReadOnly" value="False" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Please help me to solve this issue....

Comment: do you share the same database server between these two copies of your app?

Answer (score 0):

do you have installed SQL Instance in windows 7?
repleace "." instead "user-pc"